# Openpyxl - Loop through specific sheets (by index)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

What I want to do is to run a function on a couple of sheets.

So far, the only way to get close to the solution, was to use:

```
for sheet in wb.worksheets:
    ws = wb[sheet]
        pass
```

But this is supposed to get all worksheets and I was looking for a way to get specific sheets so I can run this only on them.

Also, because there are a lot of sheets, I don't want to use several:

```
ws1 = wb["P2"]
```

Is there a way to run this/get sheet names by index? Something like this:

```
for sheet in wb.worksheets[3:27]:
    ws = wb[sheet]
        pass
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution on this one.

```
sheetList = wb.sheetnames[2:47] #go from sheet 2, to sheet 47
    for sheet in sheetList:
        ws = wb[sheet]
        for col in ws.iter_cols(min_row=1, max_row=1, min_col=1, max_col=1):
            for cell in col:
                cell.value = "It worked!"
```